# How to add data to an existing Document in a Firestore Database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I currently started how to code with swift and now im standing in front of my first huge problem which I can't solve on my self now. My Problem is that after the Sign In Screen some data should be added to this users Database document in Firebase and after that transit to the Homescreen. The transition to the Homescreen works just fine, the only problem is that the Data isn't  stored in the Firebase Database object. My code looks like this:

```
    @IBAction func weiterButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let error = validateFields()
    
    if error != nil{
        //Fehler
        showError(error!)
    }else{
        //Daten aus Textfeld ziehen
        let aimedWeight = zielTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let height = groesseTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let weight = gewichtTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        if user != nil{
            db.collection("Nutzer")
                .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: user!.uid)
                .getDocuments { (snap, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        //error
                        print(err)
                    }else if snap!.documents.count != 1{
                        //error later on
                    }else{
                        //add data
                        var document = snap!.documents.first?.data()
            
                        document?.updateValue(height, forKey: "Größe")
                    
                        
                    }
                }
            
        }else{
            showError("Fehler")
        }
        toHomeScreen()
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: I suggest adding some code to check the result of updateValue for errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My first guess is that write is not completed after you navigate to the next screen. If that is indeed the cause, you'll need to wait for the write to be complete before calling `toHomeScreen()` similarly to how you already wait for the `getDocuments()` to be completed before writing.

```
@IBAction func weiterButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
let error = validateFields()

if error != nil{
    //Fehler
    showError(error!)
}else{
    //Daten aus Textfeld ziehen
    let aimedWeight = zielTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let height = groesseTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let weight = gewichtTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    if user != nil{
        db.collection("Nutzer")
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: user!.uid)
            .getDocuments { (snap, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    //error
                    print(err)
                }else if snap!.documents.count != 1{
                    //error later on
                }else{
                    //add data
                    var document = snap!.documents.first?.data()
        
                    document?.updateValue(height, forKey: "Größe") { err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            print("Document successfully updated")
                            toHomeScreen()
                        }
                    }                    
                    
                }
            }
        
    }else{
        showError("Fehler")
    }
}
```

Unrelated: I'd also recommend to store the user data under the user's UID, instead of under another auto-generated ID. UIDs are also guaranteed to be unique, and using them makes this code much simpler:

```
db.collection("Nutzer").document(user!.uid)?.updateValue(height, forKey: "Größe")...
```

Comment: Thanks again it works. Amazing. I changed the ID under which the data is stored to the uid. and my code looks so clean now thanks!

Answer (score -1):

.set will overwrite existing document.

```
const docRef = firestoreDb.collection('Nutzer').doc(uid);
return docRef.set({
                    aimedWeight : _aimedWeight,
                    height : _height,
                    weight : _weight 
                    }).then(() => {
                    return {
                        success: true
                        };
                    });
```